# Xamarin Forms Listview selecteditem set backgroundcolor not working first time

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a CustomViewRenderer, which changes the Backgroundcolor of an item in a Listview.
If I click on an item the Color changes correct.
When I load my ListView and set programmatically the ItemSource and the SelectedItem the Color is Standard Orange in Android.
The ListView.SelectedItem doesnt call the Android Renderer "OnCellPropertyChanged", at the first Time loading.

What is my mistake?

Loading ListView:

```
listNew = listDG.Where(g => g.check == true).ToList();
        listNew = listNew.OrderBy(g => g.beschreibung).ToList();
        listGegenstandZuordnungBinding = new BindingList<db.gegenstaendezuordnungliste>(listNew);
        lvGegenstaende.ItemsSource = listGegenstandZuordnungBinding;
        lvGegenstaende.ItemSelected += LvGegenstaende_ItemSelected; ;

        if (App.idgegenstandueb != 0)
        {
            List<db.gegenstaendezuordnungliste> listSelected = listNew.Where(g => g.idgegenstandueb == App.idgegenstandueb).ToList();
            if (listSelected.Count > 0)
            {
                lvGegenstaende.SelectedItem = listSelected[0];
            }
            else
            {
                if (listNew.Count > 0)
                {
                    lvGegenstaende.SelectedItem = listNew[0];
                    App.idgegenstandueb = listNew[0].idgegenstandueb;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (listNew.Count > 0)
        {
            App.idgegenstandueb = listNew[0].idgegenstandueb;
            lvGegenstaende.SelectedItem = listNew[0];
        }
```

Android Renderer:

```
protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
    {
        var listView = parent as Android.Widget.ListView;
        _selected = false;
        if (listView != null)
        {
            //    // Disable native cell selection color style - set as *Transparent*
            listView.SetSelector(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
            listView.CacheColorHint = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent.ToAndroid();
        }
        var cell = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);
        return cell;
    }

    protected override void OnCellPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCellPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        _selected = !_selected;

        var extendedViewCell = sender as CustomControl;
        if (extendedViewCell.Parent.AutomationId != null)
        {
            if (extendedViewCell.Parent.AutomationId.ToString() == "Listgegenstaende")
            {
                if (_selected)
                    extendedViewCell.View.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("4682B4");
                else
                    extendedViewCell.View.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#5096D0");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (_selected)
                extendedViewCell.View.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
            else
                extendedViewCell.View.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your event 'LvGegenstaende_ItemSelected' is being raised when you set the selected item?

Comment: Yes, after Setting lvGegenstaende.SelectedItem = listSelected[0]; the Event is raised